# PowerBlocks Sport 9.0 Exp Expansion Options

Tags: dumbbells

I recently picked up an older pair of PowerBlocks (Sport 9.0 Exp). PowerBlocks no longer makes the expansions (stage 2 or stage 3) for my model. Does anyone know of another model of PowerBlocks that would be compatible with mine?